# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have implemented the AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter.

In getFilter() Method I fetch suggestion from Server and display it.
Now If i type one by one character slowly it works very well but when i start typing fast it sometime show suggestion.

Any suggestion for how to take care of this issue?

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Log.i("TIME", "Called getfilter");
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.i("TIME", "1");
            Log.i("TIME", "2 : " + constraint);
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                autoCompletItems = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i("TIME", "Required Milis : " + (t2 - t1));
                Log.i("TIME", "Total Items : " + autoCompletItems.size());
                // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                filterResults.values = autoCompletItems;
                filterResults.count = autoCompletItems.size();
            }
            Log.i("TIME", "3: " + filterResults.count);
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            Log.i("TIME", "Called publishResults" + "   , Count : "
                    + results.count);
            clear();
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            AutoCompletItem autoCompletItem = (AutoCompletItem) resultValue;
            return autoCompletItem.getProductName();
        }

    };

    return filter;
}

protected ArrayList<AutoCompletItem> autocomplete(String string) {
    ArrayList<AutoCompletItem> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.1");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(URL_GET_SUGGESTIONS_SERVICE);
        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.2");
        int available = inputStream.available();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.3" + " Total available : " + available);
        byte[] data = new byte[available];
        inputStream.read(data);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.4");
        ItemContainer container = (ItemContainer) deserialize(data);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.5");
        resultList = (ArrayList<AutoCompletItem>) container
                .getSerializable();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.6");
        System.out.println("Check Data");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.exception " + e);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.exception " + e);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "2.finally ");
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Really late for an answer but for those who might be looking for one.

```
AutoCompleteTextView myAutoCompleteTV;
```

If you are populating your AutoCompleteTextView on the fly (possibly with an AsyncTask : to be able to come back on the UI Thread later) you can add a TextWatcher like follows

`myAutoCompleteTV.addTextChangedListener(this);`

This would be so you can populate it separately while the user inputs the characters he knows he is looking for. When he gets stuck or needs suggestions, he'll stop and that's when `myAutoCompleteTV` will not query anymore (remember I'm assuming you have a huge list)

In one of the three watchers, force the filter to show suggestions matching what is currently in the `myAutoCompleteTV`

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
     ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) myAutoCompleteTV.getAdapter
     myAdapter.getFilter().filter(myAutoCompleteTV.getText().toString());
     myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: myAutoCOmpleteTV is a AutoCompleteTextView .. it does not have any of the methods used in this solution.

Comment: @reidisaki In case you are the down voter, I see you have extensive knowledge in Android. Editing the mistake a peer did would've been better than down voting and commenting.